# Defining function to check if string is valid

Tags: python

```
letters1 = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
letters2 = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"

def is_valid(strs):
    char_b = True
    for char in range(0, len(strs)):
        if strs[char] not in (letters1 or letters2):
            char_b == False
    return char_b
```

I don't understand why this won't work, anyone mind giving me a hint? It just always returns true.

Comment: `(letters1 or letters2)` is equal to `letters1`

Comment: You may use the [string](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html) module (in particular `string.ascii_lowercase` and `string.ascii_uppercase`) instead of definining manually `letters{}`.

Comment: You might like to know about `str.isalpha()` method

Comment: generally I saw people to misspell `==` by `=` but this is first example where typo is opposite!!

Comment: Using [string.ascii_letters](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/string.html#string.ascii_letters) would be the way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to **set** `char_b`, not test for equality. Replace:

```
char_b == False
```

with

```
char_b = False
```

Your test is incorrect:

```
if strs[char] not in letters1 + letters2:
```

or simplify your function to:

```
def is_valid(strs):
    return strs.isalpha()
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! I can't believe i missed that